# Angular 4 animations is executing on init component

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

When is executing a component where is used a animations, the animation is executing, same that the state of animation is in display none,

show this gif:

[Gif](https://i.imgur.com/v0v61rV.gifv)

The animation in modal is appaer when open the component, and i want that not this.

Help me, pleaese !!

component.ts

```
trigger('openModal', [
  state('true', style({
    display: 'block',
    'transform': 'scale(1)'
  })),
  state('false', style({
    display: 'none',
    'transform': 'scale(0)'
  })),
  transition('* => *', animate('.2s'))
]),

openCancelFavorite: boolean = false;
```

component.html

```
 <div [@openModal]="openCancelFavorite" class="onbusca-favorite-remove">
    <div class="row onbusca-row">
      <div class="ml-auto col-auto">
          <i (click)="openCancelFavorite = false" class="fa fa-close onbusca-login-close"></i> 
      </div>
    </div>

      <p class="not-p onbusca-favorite-remove-message">Você tem certeza que quer remover este produto dos favoritos ?</p>

    <div class="onbusca-favorite-buttons">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Sim, remova</button>
      <button (click)="openCancelFavorite = false" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Cancelar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand! I can't see GIF.... you want toggle animation?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you just have to set the display of the class, by default, to none.

So add display: none; to onbusca-favorite-remove

```
.onbusca-favorite-remove {
    display: none;
}
```

Otherwise, you can toggle the animation on an *ngIf like so:

**Change your animation to:**

```
trigger('openModal', [
state(':enter', style({
    display: 'block',
    'transform': 'scale(1)'
})),
state(':leave', style({
    display: 'none',
    'transform': 'scale(0)'
})),
transition('* => *', animate('.2s'))
]),

openCancelFavorite: boolean = false;
```

**Change your template to:**

```
<div *ngIf="openCancelFavorite" [@openModal] class="onbusca-favorite-remove"> ... </div>
```

Comment: but, really not appaer on init the component